# Video recorded through OpenCV not loading on html

Tags: python, django, opencv

I am recording videos with the help of OpenCV. Now after the video is saved, I am trying to load that video into HTML, with the help of video and iframe tags, but it is not loading in either of the tags. I have saved the video in `.avi/.mp4` format. Locally in VLC the videos are playing fine, but are not loading in HTML.
For recording video with openCV, I have referred to : https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/web-camera-recorder-oepncv-flask.html.

Video Recording Code :

```
import cv2
import threading

class RecordingThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, camera,vname):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.isRunning = True
        self.cap = camera
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
        path = "MUES/static/Recordings/"+vname+".mp4"
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(path,fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

    def run(self):
        while self.isRunning:
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if ret:
                self.out.write(frame)

        self.out.release()

    def stop(self):
        self.isRunning = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.out.release()

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Open a camera
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
      
        # Initialize video recording environment
        self.is_record = False
        self.out = None

        # Thread for recording
        self.recordingThread = None
    
    def __del__(self):
        self.cap.release()
    
    def get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()

        if ret:
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            return jpeg.tobytes()
      
        else:
            return None

    def start_record(self,vname):
        self.is_record = True
        self.recordingThread = RecordingThread("Video Recording Thread", self.cap,vname)
        self.recordingThread.start()

    def stop_record(self):
        self.is_record = False

        if self.recordingThread != None:
            self.recordingThread.stop()
```

`Browser : Chrome`

Comment: Both AVI and MP4 are container formats. What matters are the streams inside the container and their formats.

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: What's your code? What's you audio / video codec? What's your browser?

Comment: I am following this: https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/web-camera-recorder-oepncv-flask.html.
Have done the same thing for Django. 'avi' and 'mp4' both format are struggling.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://www.encoding.com/html5-video-codec/) no browser supports MJPEG in the video tag.